# What's the difference between these two typedef?

Tags: dart

First:

```
typedef CustomBuilder<T> = Widget Function(BuildContext context, T item);
```

Second:

```
typedef Widget CustomBuilder<T>(BuildContext context, T item);
```

Both seems to work, I'd like to know is there any difference between the two?

Comment: There are a hint for changing to the first example with some description of the reason why: https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_generic_function_type_aliases.html

Comment: Thank you @julemand101, please feel free to write it in answer, and I'm happy to accept yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a hint for changing to the first example with some description of the reason why:

> With the introduction of generic functions, function type aliases (typedef void F()) couldn't express all of the possible kinds of parameterization that users might want to express. Generic function type aliases (typedef F = void Function()) fixed that issue.
>
> For consistency and readability reasons, it's better to only use one syntax and thus prefer generic function type aliases.

https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_generic_function_type_aliases.html

Comment: It's kinda said that Google itself uses both approach and doesn't stick to one, for instance, take a look [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/547674c8b550a0b14ff442a3bd6a2663c6dc7680/packages/firebase_messaging/lib/firebase_messaging.dart#L14)